# Connect to RedisCluster with go-redis (NewClusterClient)

Tags: go, kubernetes, redis, redis-cluster, go-redis

I have deployed a RedisCluster ( with redis operator ) in kubernetes.  Connect to all leaders and followers from redis-cli is fine.  However when I tried to connect with go-redis library (),  I am getting "Dial tcp: look ?: no such host" error.  Although the error seems like it can resolve the redis node but I am very positive the error is not related to resolving the host `10.216.11.150` in my case but after the library connect to `10.216.11.150`, it tried to resolve another node ( probably the slave node ?? ) but failed.  why it tried to look up "?:" ?

```
    rdb := redis.NewClusterClient(&redis.ClusterOptions{
        Addrs: []string{"10.216.11.150:6379", "10.216.15.178:6379", "10.216.12.115:6379"},
        TLSConfig: &tls.Config{
            InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        },
    })
```

I tried to use `NewUniversalClient`, if I specified one node , it can connect to the cluster, once I specified more than one node in `Addrs` it will failed with Dial tcp: look ?: no such host" error

Comment: How about checking the RedisCluster's setting?
I think there can be a node with a wrong config as you said "the slave node ??"